# SQL Server - Get the final sum of a product of two columns

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

Despite my little knwoledge of SQL Server, i'm stucked on this problem for a while:

I'm trying to get the final sum of a product of two columns, but SQL Server won't recognize my last column. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
Products.customName AS 'Name',
Ordered_Products.scanned AS 'Sent Quantity',
Charged_Products.price AS 'Product Price',
Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price AS 'Charged'
FROM Products
    JOIN Charged_Products
        ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
    JOIN Ordered_Products
        ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE
Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500 AND
Ordered_Products.scanned > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', '', '', SUM('Charged')
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

Could somebody point me in the right direction to make the query work ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to do that calculation outside of SQL and in the client code (ie. whatever calls your query, .NET, Java, SSRS etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT
Products.customName AS 'Name',
Ordered_Products.scanned AS 'Sent Quantity',
Charged_Products.price AS 'Product Price',
Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price AS 'Charged'
FROM Products
    JOIN Charged_Products
        ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
    JOIN Ordered_Products
        ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE
Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500 AND
Ordered_Products.scanned > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 'TOTAL', '', '', SUM(Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price)
FROM Products
    JOIN Charged_Products
        ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
    JOIN Ordered_Products
        ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE
Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500 AND
Ordered_Products.scanned > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd better to do this on client side.

But if you want it so much, then use `GROUPING SETS`.

```
SELECT ISNULL (Products.customName, 'TOTAL') AS 'Name'
    , Ordered_Products.scanned AS 'Sent Quantity'
    , Charged_Products.price AS 'Product Price'
    , SUM (Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price) AS 'Charged'
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Charged_Products ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
INNER JOIN Ordered_Products ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500
    AND Ordered_Products.scanned > 0
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Products.customName, Ordered_Products.scanned, Charged_Products.price),())
```

Comment: I tried using GROUPING SETS, but it doesn't seem to retrieve the right result. I'm going to stick with the answer way. More greedy for sure, but since i don't have to hande a lot of data, that should do the work. Anyway, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

[GROUPING SETS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29312/Grouping-Sets-in-T-SQL-SQL-Server) is what you probably need. Check this [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7868/0)

Also the following should work but not very sure as I have not checked it with actual data. Also it doesnt look too good in terms of performance.

```
SELECT
Products.customName AS 'Name',
Ordered_Products.scanned AS 'Sent Quantity',
Charged_Products.price AS 'Product Price',
Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price AS 'Charged'
FROM Products
JOIN Charged_Products
ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
JOIN Ordered_Products
ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE
Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500 AND
Ordered_Products.scanned > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', '', '', SUM(Ordered_Products.scanned * Charged_Products.price)
FROM Products
JOIN Charged_Products
ON Products.productsId = Charged_Products.productsId
JOIN Ordered_Products
ON Ordered_Products.productsId = Products.productsId
WHERE
Ordered_Products.ordersId = 500 AND
Ordered_Products.scanned > 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works even if it's a bit performance greedy as you said !

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE 
    ( [name] varchar(20), [attribute] INT, [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO @TableName
    ( [name], [attribute], [value])
VALUES
    ('Product1', 2, 15),
    ('Product2', 3, 30),
    ('Product3', 3, 20)

select name,attribute,value,attribute * value As Total from @TableName
UNION ALL 
Select 'T0tal','','',SUM(attribute * value)  from @TableName
```